# How do I narrow a JetBrains IDE tool window?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In some of my JetBrains IDEs my the tool windows launched for the bottom bar open to fill the full width of my IDE window, while in others they are limited to the width of the middle pane of the IDE window. I prefer the latter, but can't figure out how to get there from the former.

How do I narrow a JetBrains IDE tool window to the width of the middle pane of my IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Appearance & Behavior | Appearance`
3. `Widescreen tool window layout` option under `Window options` section.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I remember now! Pretty obscure setting (not helped by having "wide" make things narrower)!